# when using laravel scout, searchable() isn't updating related models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-scout

I am having an issue getting related models to update with scout elastic search.

```
$event->priceranges()->delete();
$event->priceranges()->Create([
       'price' => $ticket['ticket_price']
]);
$event->update([ 
      'show_times' => $request->showtimes,
]);
$event->searchable();
```

In my database I see the event and price range tables update. However when I look at my elastic search data, only data on the event has been updated. Any related models are not updated.

If I make a second update to the model and price range model, then the elastic search data shows my data from the first update I made (it is always one update behind for related models)
I tried doing

```
$event->pricerange->searchable()
```

but gives me an error because I don't have a searchable index for pricerange, I am just using my event model and its relationship to index. Is there a way to force the update other than searchable()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your relationship is being indexed in the `Event` model index, correct?

Probably it's not being updated because the relationships are already loaded, and Laravel doesn't update the relationship data that is already loaded, for example:

```
$event = Event::with('priceranges')->first()
var_dump($event->priceranges->count()): // outputs for example 5

$event->priceranges()->create([...]);
var_dump($event->priceranges->count()): // still outputs 5, meaning that the created pricerange is not loaded
```

So, to fix this issue you can reload the model before calling `searchable()`:

```
$event = $event->fresh();
$event->searchable();
```

But, note that everytime you update, the searchable method is already being called, so you will be indexing it two times on every update.

So, alternatively you can update your `toSearchableArray()` method in `Event` model to get a fresh model before returning the data (I'm assuming that you are using the `babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver`).

Comment: Omg this was such an amazing answer. Thank you for taking the time to explain it. Your solution worked and I will also look into the toSearchableArray option. ( I am using the babenkovian plugin)